# How to select only one type of record if it exist else select another type in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Let's say I have a result like the following that comes from a complex set of queries from multiple tables (it's not a table) using Oracle Server in background.

This comes when I have a where condition like `type in ('A','B')` . I have other types too in the source tables but right now I'm working with only these two types.

| ID | code | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | A |
| 2 | 214 | B |
| 3 | 336 | A |
| 1 | 245 | B |
| 2 | 214 | A |
| 4 | 123 | B |

Now I want to have only 1 record for a single ID. That is, type A if it exist else type B. If both exists for the same ID then only type A.

There are additional columns to this result where the **data remains same for a single ID** except the **code** and **type**

The result should be something like the following

| ID | code | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | A |
| 3 | 336 | A |
| 2 | 214 | A |
| 4 | 123 | B |

I tried using group function with an outer query but cant seem apply any group function over the whole result.

I tried using union with each type on its own. But it again gives both types.

I'm not sure how can I get my desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER()-functionality to achieve this result, e.g.

```
WITH YOUR_TABLE_DATA (ID,CODE,TYPE)
AS
(
     SELECT 1,  123,'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 , 214,    'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 , 336 ,   'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 1 , 245     ,'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 , 214 ,   'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 4,  123 ,   'B' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT X.ID,X.CODE,X.TYPE FROM
(  
  SELECT Y.ID,Y.CODE,Y.TYPE,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Y.ID ORDER BY Y.TYPE ASC)XCOL 
  FROM YOUR_TABLE_DATA Y
)X WHERE X.XCOL=1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/aBbWTqZP